# Compiler infering the template argument

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, decltype, declval

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    public:

    A(T &t)
    : t_(t){}

    T t_;
};


int main()
{
    int value;
    A<decltype(value)> a(value);
    // what I wish for : A a(value); 
    // which does not compile "missing template argument before 'a'"
}
```

Is there a way in the declaration of A (or somewhere else) to hint the compiler that T should be automatically resolved to the type passed to the constructor ?

(ideally c++11, but happy to hear about less old versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you can create a simple `make_A` function like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(T &t) : t_(t) {}

    T t_;
};

template <typename T>
A<T> make_A(T&& t) {
    return A<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    int value = 0;
    auto a = make_A(value);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+A+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++A(T+%26t)+:+t_(t)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++T+t_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0AA%3CT%3E+make_A(T%26%26+t)+%7B%0A++return+A%3CT%3E(std::forward%3CT%3E(t))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+value+%3D+0%3B%0A++++auto+a+%3D+make_A(value)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 6):

C++17 does it out of the box (or with the help of deduction guides), previous versions cannot.

Answer (score 4):

As answered by @Quentin, this is only possible starting in C++17. However, if you're fine with calling a function to create your `A` objects, the following should do what you want in C++11:

```
template <class T, class NonRefT = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>
A<NonRefT> create_A (T && t) {
  return A<NonRefT>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

// Or even closer to your original code:
template <class T>
auto create_A (T && t) -> A<decltype(t)> {
  return A<decltype(t)>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

I used [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) based on your use of `decltype`, though you might want to use [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) instead.

```
int main () {
  int value = 5;
  auto a = create_A(value);
}
```

If I remember correctly the example code has an edge-case where it does not work as expected pre-C++17. The compiler will elide the copy/move constructor to create `a` from the rvalue returned by `create_A()`. However, it will check during compilation whether `A`'s copy/move constructor (which it won't use) is available/accessible. Starting from C++17 the copy/move elision is done "properly" and no copy/move constructor is necessary for such code. (Also, I might be misremembering and it might be checking for copy/move assignment instead.)

Comment: If I recall correctly it is not guaranteed to elide copy/move pre-C++17